# How to update tar to version 1.30+ in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, tar, gitlab

I work with the gitlab-ee docker image to install my local gitlab.
This docker image has the OS Ubuntu 16.04 and can be found here: gitlab/gitlab-ee in hub.docker.

Within these image tar in version 1.28 is installed.

For any gitlab backup, the docs say 1.30 is needed, which is allready 2 years old.

With apt-get I can't install the newer version.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can always install a binary package from here: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/. Unpack it to a directory with a distinct name; maybe You will also have to search and install the same way the dependencies. Then You will need to add these directories to Your $PATH variable.

**Detailed explanation would be:**

Download the archive (e.g., tar-1.31.tar.gz); I will assume it going to the $HOME/Downloads directory.

```
$ [ ! -d $HOME/bin ] && mkdir $HOME/bin; mkdir $HOME/bin/tar1.31
$ cd $HOME/
$ mv $HOME/Downloads/tar-1.31.tar.gz ./
$ tar -xzf tar-1.31.tar.gz
$ cd tar-1.31
$ configure --prefix=$HOME/bin/tar1.31 DEFAULT_RMT_DIR=/etc # if there exists a file /etc/rmt
$ make -j 4 # 4 is number of CPU cores available for You
$ make install
$ make clean
```

Also, You can create a new alternative so as not to modify Your path variable:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /bin/tar tar $HOME/bin/tar1.31/tar 1
```

Comment: As a Linux newbie I have now clue how to do this... Can you help me with a few lines of commands please?